# Is there a way that i can push historical data into druid over http?

Tags: druid

I have an IOT project and want to use Druid as Time Series DBMS. Sometimes the IOT device may lose the network and will re-transfer the historical data and real-time data when reconnecting to the server. I know the Druid can ingest real-time data over http push/pull and historical data over http pull or KIS, but i can't find the document about ingesting historical data over http push.

Is there a way that i can send historical data into druid over http push?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few options here:

1. Keep pushing historical data to the same kafka topic (or other streaming source) and do a rejection based on message-timestamp inside Druid. This simplifies your application architecture and let druid handle expired events rejection
2. Use batch ingestion for historical data. You push the historical data to another Kafka topic, run a spark/gobblin/any other index job to get the data to HDFS. Then do a batch ingestion onto Druid. But remember that Druid overwrites any real-time segments with batch segments for the specified windowPeriod. So if the historical data is not complete, you run into data loss. To prevent this, you could always pump real-time data into hadoop as well and do a de-duplication on the HDFS data periodically and ingest into Druid. As you can see this is a complicated architecture, but this can result in minimal data loss.

If I were you, I would simplify and send all data to the same streaming source like Kafka. I would index segments in Druid based on my message's timestamp and not current time (which is the default I believe).

Comment: We dont use Kafka, and may be not used it in the near future. We want to use http push to send real-time/historical data, and dont want to involve a new third-party component.

Comment: That case, you can still use http push, but push to a custom server which pumps data to HDFS. HttpFS can be used to push data to HDFS via http. I have used a memory-mapped IO library (like flume, chronicle, etc.) to collect and push data to HDFS. The bottomline is get the data to HDFS somehow and do batch ingestion.

Comment: And for the option #1 above, you dont have to use Kafka necessarily. The point was about using message-based timestamp for druid to ignore late data

Answer (score 0):

kafka indexing service released recently guarantees exactly once ingestion.

Refer the below link - http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html

If you still want to ingest over http, you can checkout tranquility server. It has some mechanisms built-in for handling duplicates.